# How do I implement CRON job scheduler with PHP for Heroku application?

Tags: php, heroku, scheduled-tasks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Running Cron Tasks on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611914/running-cron-tasks-on-heroku)

The application is Facebook App hosted by Heroku. App details: PHP on the server side and Javascript/YUI on the client side. Data is saved on MySql database. A scheduled report, should be added to query users activity. I believe the best way is using CRON job but I have no idea how to implement CRON and how to register a CRON job(or what ever) in Heroku.