# Is there a way to run scheduled jobs on Heroku without spinning off a new dyno?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am looking for something like [Heroku Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler), but with the possibility to run the jobs once every 5 minutes.

Looks like Heroku supports [Clockwork](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/clock-processes-ruby), but it is not obvious weather it is billed like a dyno, or only by the actual running time of the jobs.

In other words, my job might run 15 seconds every 5 minutes so I am looking for something that charges me `15 * 12 * 24` seconds per day (72 minutes per day).

Is this possible with Heroku?

Comment: Setting up a cron task, and invoking it locally via `heroku rake cron` seems to be one option. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2709180/429758 I haven't tried it though...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you need, but you can set up a cron job, to run at scheduled times. And this would be running the rake task.

Answer (score 0):

Check our the [hirefire gem](https://github.com/meskyanichi/hirefire). This will spin up a new dyno only when there is something to be done in Delayed Job or Resque. You can combine this with the Heroku Scheduler or Clockwork if you need to run jobs at specific intervals.