# How to run a PHP script , which took hours to complete in Heroku?

Tags: php, heroku

I have a PHP script which sends a message to a number of users, with 6 mins delay in between. SO if there is 30 users, the script should run for 3 hours, to complete sending message to all 30 users. I tried  [Background Jobs with Workers in PHP](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-workers), but the script stops after 30 minutes. Is there any way to increase the timeout, or is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: use cron jobs. Here is how to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737407/how-to-create-cron-job-using-php

Comment: but i have to get the list of users id. And then send message to each on of them , how can i implement that using cron.

Comment: save your last sent user's personna in somewhere (file, db etc.) when your cron works, read it from there and step onto next one. This way, you'll use way less resources

Comment: Do u know how to start a cron job in heroku?

Comment: you can use either [scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler) or [custom clock process](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes) or you can check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611914/running-cron-tasks-on-heroku

Comment: i already tried this, The custom clock process only available to python nd java. then this daily scheduler has only min 10mins interval.

Comment: there's also the 3rd option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168571/discussion-between-jerin-a-mathews-and-cemal).

Answer (score 1):

set_time_limit — Limits the maximum execution time

[`set_time_limit ( 10800 )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Answer (score 0):

So at last what I did is, I start a cron job which calls this script every 5 mins. In the script, I check a file whether it contains any message, if there is, I will send it to users if not ignore.

So when I set up the message to sent to users, I will save the message and list of users in different files. After sending the message to each user, I delete them from the list. As soon as the users list become empty, I delete the message from the file too. In this way, the script will know, that it sends the message to all the users. By far it's working well. I am using `cron-job.org` for creating cron job. It's free in there.