# How to change a property in a MongoDB collection every Sunday at 00:01 Midnight in app that written under Node JS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, mongoose

I have an app on Heroku that's written in Node JS and uses Mongo DB as a database.

In Mongo I have a collection GamePlan that one of the properties is Status :

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const GamePlanSchema = new Schema({

  LeadId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  PackageId: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },


  Status: {           // This one needs to be changed every Sunday Midnight 00:01 to value "4"
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  InsertDate: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = GamePlan = mongoose.model(
  "gameplan",
  GamePlanSchema
);
```

I'm looking for some kind of a task that would work automatically and change all the relevant documents in `GamePlan`.

What would be the best approach to solve this ?

Comment: you can use a cron in your node.js app that updates the status on a given date

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it just using nodejs, you could look at following pacakge - https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cron

If you want to let Heroku handle it, you could follow this link - [Running Cron Tasks on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611914/running-cron-tasks-on-heroku)